# Stack Overflow site loads in plain html page

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-interface

Sometimes (Don't know when and why), Stack Overflow website opens in plain HTML format. As it is show in below picture.

> [image]

This happening only [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and not with other Stack Exchange website. I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: Dear I have opened this page at least 20 time within 2 mins. Forget about slow speed its running very smoothly. And for your information I have Re-opened Chrome and Problem got solved. Now my point is why it happened?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: @DaveChen : I don't know what id AdBlock. Can you explain me, please.

Comment: Never-mind that, have you tried running in Incognito-mode?

Comment: @hims056 : Problem is same but causes are not same. Since I Re-opened the browser problem got solved.

Comment: @RJ1990 - Problem is same then it's a duplicate. Causes are not same then you can add your answer there.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. Causes are different that i assume from answers made there. What cause to my system that I didn't found. :)